# Bonferroni (or BH) correction for multiple t-test?

Tags: anova, t-test, bonferroni

I'm studying the kinematics differences between males and females examined at two different specific walking speeds (slow/fast). Specifically, I'm exploring:

a) slow speed vs high speed (dependent t-test)

b) slow speed males vs high speed males (independent t-test)

c) slow speed females vs high speed females (independent t-test)

d) slow speed males vs slow speed females (independent t-test)

e) high speed males vs high speed females (independent t-test)

I have two questions:

1. Is it correct to use multiple t-test instead of ANOVA?
2. Do I have to use a Bonferroni (or Benjamini-Hochberg) for all the FIVE tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be to start from ANOVA with interaction `male*walking_speed` and only if you reject the interaction you may proceed with, what is called, the *post-hoc analysis*.

Testing separately each group leads, typically, to a loss of power, so you do it only if it's worth the money, i.e. if you reject the $H_0$ that interaction is not significant or if you are interested only in a few comparisons out of many.

Comment: Ok thank you. However, I have a doubt: Is it correct to run ANOVA since I'm not actually comparing different groups, but I'm just splitting the two main groups (walking_speed) into sex and then into the two speeds?

Comment: put it like this, you have a big urn with all your individuals and two ways to distinguish them, sex and walking_speed; the letters are thus grouping factors.

Comment: from a diff. perspective is like you have a single grouping factor with four levels: `slow_speed_F`, `slow_speed_M`, `high_speed_F`, and `high_speed_M`.

Comment: yeah I've got it. so I can just run the Anova with these "four groups". Cool. 
Help me with this issue too: I would just run the t-test to point out the general differences between the two speeds independently of the sex (slow vs fast); do you think is it correct? Or maybe it is unnecessary because I'm already discussing the specific classifications.

Comment: slow vs fast is also handled by ANOVA with interaction in the answer, you will see it in the anova table, depending on how you code the levels of the factors.

Comment: Thank you utobi; I was not sure if ANOVA was correct, but thanks to you now, I clarified my doubts.

Comment: Utobi I have a question. Actually the individuals did both walking, not just one. I mean that the individual 1 did two exams, one at slow speed and the other one at high speed. Is it correct to consider it as independent?

Comment: Well in such a case you have paired samples, so observation may be dependent and classical ANOVA doesn't meet the assumptions. In this case, you may consider ANOVA with random effects.